# Get information about customer without password of user using the Shopware 6 REST API

Tags: rest, shopware, shopware6

I am trying to get information about a customer using the REST API of Shopware 6 (using this [API](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/b3A6ODI2NTY0Ng-get-information-about-current-customer)). Therefor I need a ContextToken for that user. The only way to get a context token for a user is to [log him in](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/b3A6ODI2NTY1Mg-log-in-a-customer), but for that I need the password of a user which I do not have. Is there any way to get the ContextToken of a user with only his email address or hist customer id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shopware comes with 2 different APIs, the Store-API and the Admin-API. Refer to the [docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/integrations-api).

The [Store-API](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/YXBpOjgyNjU2MzM-endpoints) is there to build a storefront and thus you need to authenticate as the user using that API.

When you build custom integrations you should use the [Admin-API](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/YXBpOjEyMjgzNTQ4-endpoints), as that API can be used for CRUD-like operations on all entities of the system. For the admin API you can generate an API-Token and use it to query data of all customers.